# Knockout foreach loop iterating same data element

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have an array of 4 elements and are passed by binding to foreach loop.

```
   <ul data-bind="foreach: relatives">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: First"></span>
            <span data-bind="text: Last"></span>
            <span>
                <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a> 
                <a href="#" class="tag-delete">Delete</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

For some reason my output is giving me a relative four times in my debug I only have four relatives in my data array I made observable. My html shows redudant entries. It's pretty clear cut I didn't make a mistake with my array it clearly has 4 elements to it but the foreach loop is acting strange.

Javascript using Knockout:

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "Doe", Address: "76 Hero Ave" },
    { Id: 2, First: "Bill", Last: "Doe", Address: "467 Nantucket Rd" },
    { Id: 3, First: "Sue", Last: "Doe", Address: "467 Nantucket Rd" },
    { Id: 4, First: "Jane", Last: "Doe", Address: "76 Hero Ave" },
];

var viewModel = {
    // data
    relatives: ko.observableArray(data),
    firstNameToAdd: ko.observable(""),
    lastNameToAdd: ko.observable(""),

    // behaviors
    addRelative: function () {
        this.relatives.push({ First: this.firstNameToAdd(), Last: this.lastNameToAdd()        });
        this.firstNameToAdd("");
        this.lastNameToAdd("");
    }
};

$(document).on("click", ".tag-delete", function () {
    var itemToRemove = ko.dataFor(this);
    viewModel.relatives.remove(itemToRemove);
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

With the added on click delete from the viewModel code block added, my list will no longer display anything. My debug shows I have nothing in data as well and doesn't show up.

Comment: could you post your javascript code?

Comment: Sure I just added it for ya. That's the whole thing. I'm just trying to display it right.

Comment: Can you see the issue in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/wVdnL/?

Comment: Nope looks like just how I'd expect it to look.

Comment: Stupid question, but you are looking and refreshing the correct page? I know that in the past I have sat and thought that something hasnt been working, then realised I was looking at the live site rather than the test site :P

Comment: Still looking at the same site. I close and run my debug again and get the same thing over and over. I did something else that cause another weird issue I wonder if it will help solve this. Give me a min to get the code in again and and edit the post.

Comment: Just added the new code it's at the bottom of the javascript. I put it into the fiddle and it works like I'd expect but mine my list no longer will show. My current references are: /// <reference path="knockout.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.7.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.18.js" />

Comment: ok I didn't have jquery 1.7.1.min in my layout referenced but I still have the same problem with the list showing 4 elements of each item. So I have 4 John Doe elements and when I click delete it removes all four that are displayed and from the list.

Comment: What version of knockout are you using? Anything been changed in the version you are using?

Comment: Sorry I got pulled off this and onto something else I haven't been able to get back to it yet. I do apologize for that.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: i am facing same problem. did u found any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

View

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: relatives">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: First"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Last"></span>
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="tag-edit">Edit</a> 
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Delete</a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1, First: "John", Last: "Doe", Address: "76 Hero Ave" },
    { Id: 2, First: "Bill", Last: "Doe", Address: "467 Nantucket Rd" },
    { Id: 3, First: "Sue", Last: "Doe", Address: "467 Nantucket Rd" },
    { Id: 4, First: "Jane", Last: "Doe", Address: "76 Hero Ave" },
];

​var viewModel = {
    // data
    relatives: ko.observableArray(data),
    firstNameToAdd: ko.observable(""),
    lastNameToAdd: ko.observable(""),


    // behaviors
    addRelative: function() {
        this.relatives.push({
            First: this.firstNameToAdd(),
            Last: this.lastNameToAdd()
        });
        this.firstNameToAdd("");
        this.lastNameToAdd("");

    },

    remove: function(item) {
        viewModel.relatives.remove(item);
    },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```